# Customizing Window with PathSvg

Tags: qt, qml, window, shapes

Here's what I've now in my `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Test Window")

    property double iconSize: 24

    RowLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle{
            id: rect
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: iconSize
            ListView{
                id: lv
                model: ViewModel.views
                anchors.fill: parent
                delegate: ItemDelegate{
                    width: iconSize
                    height: iconSize
                    ColumnLayout{
                        Shape {
                            ShapePath {
                                fillColor: hovered? "blue" : highlighted? "green" : "black"
                                PathSvg { path: modelData.icon }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    onClicked: {
                        lv.currentIndex = index
                        load.setSource(modelData.view)
                    }
                    highlighted: ListView.isCurrentItem
                    background: Rectangle{
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        color: "transparent"
                    }
                }
                Component.onCompleted: load.setSource("a.qml")
            }
        }

        Loader{
            id: load
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.margins: 5
        }

        DropShadow{
            anchors.fill: rect
            source: rect
            radius: 10
            samples: 15
            color: "black"
        }

        DropShadow{
            anchors.fill: load
            source: load
            radius: 10
            samples: 15
            color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

I get these warnings/error when I run the application:

```
qrc:/main.qml:58:9: QML DropShadow: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
qrc:/main.qml:66:9: QML DropShadow: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
```

I've to have `anchors.fill: elementId` in both `DropShadow` to make it work, right? Here's how it looks:

[image]

First, those `SVG` aren't smooth, I've tried with some properties listed [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shapes-shapepath.html) BUT those actually don't help! What do I've to do to make those look better?

Second, I want to replace the default `Window` Title Bar with another `Rectangle` on top with `DropShadow` and add 3 more `SVG` as minimize, maximize and close buttons BUT haven't yet found any example of customizing default QtQuick Window.

**EDIT**

Here's `Constants.h` that holds SVG Path Data:

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H
#include<QString>

const QString AIcon = "M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2M11,7A2,2 0 0,0 9,9V17H11V13H13V17H15V9A2,2 0 0,0 13,7H11M11,9H13V11H11V9Z";
const QString BIcon = "M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2M15,10.5V9A2,2 0 0,0 13,7H9V17H13A2,2 0 0,0 15,15V13.5C15,12.7 14.3,12 13.5,12C14.3,12 15,11.3 15,10.5M13,15H11V13H13V15M13,11H11V9H13V11Z";
const QString CIcon = "M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2M11,7A2,2 0 0,0 9,9V15A2,2 0 0,0 11,17H13A2,2 0 0,0 15,15V14H13V15H11V9H13V10H15V9A2,2 0 0,0 13,7H11Z";

#endif // CONSTANTS_H
```

here's `View.h`, the model:

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include "Property.h"

class View : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    PROPERTY(QString, icon)
    PROPERTY(QString, view)
public:
    View(QString icon, QString view) : m_icon(icon), m_view(view) {}
};

#endif // VIEW_H
```

here's `VM.h`, the ViewModel

```
#ifndef VM_H
#define VM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QtCore>
#include "Property.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include "view.h"

class VM : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    PROPERTY(QVector<View*>, views)
public:
    explicit VM(QObject *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

};

#endif // VM_H
```

here's `VM.cpp`:

```
#include "vm.h"

VM::VM(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ViewModel", this);
    engine.load("qrc:/main.qml");

    m_views.push_back(new View(AIcon, "a.qml"));
    m_views.push_back(new View(BIcon, "b.qml"));
    m_views.push_back(new View(CIcon, "c.qml"));
    emit viewsChanged();
}
```

here's `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "vm.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    VM vm;
    return app.exec();
}
```

the `PROPERTY` macro:

```
#ifndef PROPERTY_H
#define PROPERTY_H

#define PROPERTY(QType, name) \
    Q_PROPERTY(QType name READ name WRITE set##name NOTIFY name##Changed) \
    public: \
    QType name(){return m_##name;}\
    void set##name(QType value){m_##name = value; emit name##Changed();} \
    Q_SIGNAL void name##Changed(); \
    private: \
    QType m_##name;


#endif // PROPERTY_H
```

and here's `a.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text{
            text: "A View"
            font.pointSize: 18
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```

`a.qml`, `b.qml` and `c.qml` are same except the `text`. For `b.qml` and I've `B View` as `text` and `C View` for `c.qml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `flags: Qt.Window | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint` and `flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint` works. With the first I get a resize grip by default and a outer black border but the TitleBar gets taller than what I expect:

[image]

It always is shown in my Taskbar. With the latter it's perfect:

[image]

no outer border, no resize capability by default and it doesn't even appear in Taskbar. In both cases I've to handle the dragging manually!