# How to declare a property of type EventHandler (slot?) in Custom Component and assign function for that in its usage

Tags: qt, qml, custom-component, eventhandler

For my Custom window, shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680102/customizing-window-with-pathsvg), I've created a Component named `PathButton`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12

Item {
    property alias pathData: svg.path
    width: 24
    height: 24
    Shape {
        ShapePath {
            fillColor: "black"
            PathSvg {
                id: svg
                path: pathData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and used it to `minimize`, `maximize` and `close` the window like this:

```
RowLayout{
    Layout.preferredWidth: 100
    anchors.right: title.right
    PathButton{
        pathData: ViewModel.minimizeIcon
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: mainWindow.showMinimized()
        }
    }
    PathButton{
        pathData: ViewModel.maximizeIcon
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            //this doesn't restore the window to its Normal state, showMaximized() is called always
            onClicked: mainWindow.Maximized? mainWindow.showNormal() : mainWindow.showMaximized()
        }
    }
    PathButton{
        pathData: ViewModel.closeIcon
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: mainWindow.close()
        }
    }
}
```

in all those I've a `MouseArea`. What I want is to have that `MouseArea` in my Custom Component and declare a property of type `eventhandler/signal/slot` and assign that handler for `onClicked` like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12

Item {
    property alias pathData: svg.path
    property alias handler: mouse.onClicked
    width: 24
    height: 24
    Shape {
        ShapePath {
            fillColor: "black"
            PathSvg {
                id: svg
                path: pathData
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea{
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: handler
    }
}
```

and in its usage I want to assign the relevant function like this:

```
PathButton{
    pathData: ViewModel.minimizeIcon
    handler: mainWindow.showMinimized()
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's what I've in `PathButton.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12

Item {
    id: root
    property alias pathData: svg.path
    signal onClicked()

    width: 24
    height: 24
    Shape {
        ShapePath {
            fillColor: "black"
            PathSvg {
                id: svg
                path: pathData
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: root.onClicked()
    }
}
```

and in `main.qml` I get that error and when I hit run with that error, in Application Output I get another error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is simply a signal:

```
// PathButton.qml
Item {
    id: root
    signal clicked()

    ...

    MouseArea {
        onClicked: root.clicked()
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
PathButton {
    onClicked: mainWindow.showMinimized()
}
```

Comment: that didn't work for me, see edit part for the errors

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. The signal should just be `clicked`. The signal handler is still `onClicked`.

Comment: used that `on` and first letter capitalized convention in `Connections` like `function onCppSignal` BUT didn't know that `signal` keyword exists in qml!